# Return of LOV in SELECT-LIST order by output

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

in my application I've got a page, where the user should be able to select a creator for a task via a select list which got it's values from a LOV.
Thats the Code of it:

```
select case
       when USER_STATUS = '0' then '*INACTIVE* '|| LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
       else  LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
       end as d, CID r
from   TABLE_TEST
order by d asc;
```

The declaration of my table is the following.

```
create TABLE TABLE_TEST(
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(75 BYTE),
    CDISPLAYNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    USER_STATUS NUMBER DEFAULT 1 --Can also be 0 (inactive) or 3 (System User)
);
```

So my problem is, that the return value in the SELECT-LIST is shown like this
`*INACTIVE* Surname5,Prename5
*INACTIVE* Surname6,Prename6
*INACTIVE* Surname7,Prename7
Surname1,Prename1
Surname2,Prename2
Surname3,Prename3
Surname4,Prename4`

but I want it to look like this
`Surname1,Prename1
Surname2,Prename2
Surname3,Prename3
Surname4,Prename4
*INACTIVE* Surname5,Prename5
*INACTIVE* Surname6,Prename6
*INACTIVE* Surname7,Prename7`

Now for my question. I want the users marked as *INACTIVE* placed below the "normal" user but the "normal" user ordered alphabetically so the simple `order by d desc` does not work for me. I don't know if it can be solved in the settings of my ApEx page or in the SQL-Code itself.
I hope you understand my problem and come forward with a solution :)

Comment: You can use CASE WHEN in ORDER BY as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE in ORDER BY and add a '1' and '0' respectively to the start of the string to prioritise the sorting

```
SELECT case
   when USER_STATUS = '0' then '*INACTIVE* '|| LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
   else  LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
   end as d
FROM TABLE_TEST
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN USER_STATUS = '0' THEN  '1' || d
  ELSE '0' || d 
  END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting your definition for table as below,

```
 create TABLE TABLE_TEST(
                         LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(75 BYTE),
                         CDISPLAYNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
                         USER_STATUS NUMBER DEFAULT 1 --Can also be 0 (inactive) or 3 (System User)
                        );
```

Some of the dummy data inserted in the table as below :

```
 select * from table_test;

 LAST_NAME  CDISPLAYNAME    USER_STATUS
     A              T1        1
     B              T1        1
     B1             T2        0
     B2             T3        0
     B3             T4        1
```

When I fire your given query which you posted above :

```
  select 
       case
       when USER_STATUS = '0' 
       then '*INACTIVE* '|| LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
       else  LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
        end as d, CID r
   from TABLE_TEST
  order by d asc;
```

Table does not hold any CID column so It's not working.
So after removing CID column,

```
  select 
       case
       when USER_STATUS = '0' 
       then '*INACTIVE* '|| LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
       else  LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
        end as d
   from TABLE_TEST
  order by d asc;
```

Output is :

```
 D
 *INACTIVE* B1,T2
 *INACTIVE* B2,T3
  A,T1
  B,T1
  B3,T4
```

So the changed query is :

```
   WITH T as
           (select case
               when USER_STATUS = '0' 
               then '*INACTIVE* '|| LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
               else  LAST_NAME || ',' || CDISPLAYNAME 
               end as d, CDISPLAYNAME r
              from   TABLE_TEST
             order by d asc)

             select * from T order by d desc;
```

So the output is:

```
    D               R
    B3,T4           T4
    B,T1            T1
    A,T1            T1
  *INACTIVE* B2,T3  T3
  *INACTIVE* B1,T2  T2
```

So All the inactive data appears at last.

Comment: Please post your expected output data in your question by edit

Comment: Did it. Sorry to not mention, that this is only my test database and the CID is only entered in my productive database on which I don't want to test